# $\phi^3$ theories in 2+1 dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory

I quite often see papers considering a $\phi^4$ theory in three spacetime dimensions, but rarely do I see papers with $\phi^3$ terms. I understand that these kinds of interactions terms can have problems, but they can be defined sensibly in 4 dimensions by considering so-called bi-adjoint scalar fields, where each field is charged under the adjoint of two gauge groups, e.g. two copies of $SU(N)$ (these kinds of models even show up in some string theories).

To be concrete, what I am thinking about is a theory defined in e.g. 4D by a Lagrangian

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac12\partial_\mu\phi^{aa'}\partial^\mu\phi^{aa'} - \lambda f^{abc}f^{a'b'c'}\phi^{aa'}\phi^{bb'}\phi^{cc'},
$$
where $\phi$ is a scalar field and $a$ and $a'$ are e.g. $SU(N)$ indices.

Is there some kind of obstruction to defining such a $\phi^3$ theory in three dimensions? Or any kind of $D=3$ scalar theory with a $\phi^3$ interaction?

Comment: 4+ dimensions? Don't you mean 6- dimensions?

Comment: @Qmechanic : I think what OP refers to is that fact that $\phi^3$ theories can be defined in 4d (as super-renormalizable) or in 6d theories. But I'm confused if whether OP is writing about a scalar field theory or a gauge theory.

Comment: @Schroedinger'sDog  $\phi^3$ is renormalizable in $d=3$.  But it's not stable unless there's a $\phi^4$ interaction.  $\phi^4$ on the other hand has no continuum limit in $d > 3$.

Comment: @user1504 You are right, I sort of mistook the lack of a ground state in my head for renormalizability.

Comment: @Qmechanic I figured that Schroedinger'sDog gave the answer, but either way for clarity I've given the 4D theory. I have seen them defined in general $D \geq 4$ as emerging from ambitwistor string theories in e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08771

Comment: Which page? OP's mentioning of 4D does not seem relevant. The limiting dimension seems to be 6D.

Comment: @Akoben   It's not stable in the sense that the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below.

Comment: @Akoben: The ground state energy can go to $-\infty$. The Hamiltonian is not bounded from below. You can see this in Srednicki's book, Chapter 9 (he does it for 4d, but an analogous statement goes through for 3d).